# Top-fixed navbar with alert above it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page that's using bootstrap 4.5

I'm struggling to add an alert above the fixed-top navbar. The alert is at the moment sitting on top of the navbar hiding half of it.

How can I keep the navbar top-fixed and yet have an alert above it?

My alert code is very simple:

```
<div th:fragment="covid-alert" class="covid-alert alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    ...some text...
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
</div>
```

and the navbar is simply:

```
<nav id="main-navbar" th:fragment="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
 ... 
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you share your css?

Comment: It's all native bootstrap 4 classes, except for my covid-alert class; its code is:

.covid-alert {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add `sticky-top` to your navbar
and wrap your covid alert with a header.

I created a sample you may check this link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-p5fcgf?file=index.html